# How to render java.time.localdate in grails gform

Tags: java, grails, taglib

How to render java.time.localdate in grails gform.
In browser I can't see field for java.time.localdate property.

Comment: Welcome to stack Overflow. Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) are some useful links on how to complete a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Let clear your question first.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the g: tag library?
`<g:formatDate format="yyyy-MM-dd" date="${date}"/>`